# Any good method to identify the principal components on a low dimension timeseries dataset?

Tags: time-series, pca, k-means

I have a low dimension (only 8 dimension) Time Series dataset of simple z-score standardized numerical data. Number of raw data point is about 2000 x 8.

I tried running PCA on the dataset by splitting the data into 10 periods of time, and I got 8 PCs obviously for each 200 data points.

My goal is not to reduce the dimension but instead want to see if I can get a set of stable Principal components loadings on the eigenvectors over the period of time, and can use the eigenvalue to understand the PCs behaviour over time.

I understand PCA algorithsm will generate eigenvectors that potentially in exact opposite direction (i.e. +/- sign flipped), but my problem is in addition to that sometimes the PCs are switching positions, e.g. suddenly PC7 becomes next period's PC3.

My "rough" thought is perhaps I can treat each of those period (total 10) the set of PCs being treated as 8-dimension point in a hypercube, and then I apply K-Mean Clustering with 8 clusters to see if I can group the nearest points together. But exactly how to do it, I am not immediately sure.

I wonder whether there are any good method to help labelling the PCs. For example maybe the first period PC0 and the second period PC1 and the third period PC5 are actually the same component.

Comment: Humm… isn’t is that in most PCA implementations, the eigenvectors are sorted according to the absolute value of the eigenvalue? I.e. after diagonalizing the matrix $XX^t$ of the time series points you should see values of decreasing absolute value on the diagonal… if that is not the case then maybe you can try to re-order them manually after the PCA?

Comment: And if that does not work then you need to check: do the eigenvalues change the order just because of the sign or do they change the order because of statistical fluctuations (this is a bit tricky to define and to figure out… maybe you look at them by eye first to get a feeling) or are they really completely different? In the latter case there apparently is no common pattern…

Comment: Yes almost all PCA implementation the eigenvalue are sorted, i.e. PC0 is supposed to be explaining most of the variance, and PC1 explains less and so on. My issue is related to time series settings. For example I divided the 8 variables time series in monthly batches. I can eyeball identify the PC0, and it got moved to PC1 or PC2 in some other subsequent batches. My question is that, is there any algorithm or method to do this identification, so that I know the PC0 in the first batch is actually moved to the 2nd PC position in the next batch (i.e. explained less covariance due to time change).